# How does certain fragment lifecycle callbacks get called before that of its host activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, activity-lifecycle

[image: Logs of lifecycle callbacks of fragment and its host activity]

Why 'OnAttach','onStart','OnCreate' callbacks of fragment are called before that of activity ?

Comment: Where are you logging your activity callbacks - before or after the call to the `super` method?

Comment: After the `super` method .

Comment: Have you tried logging both before and after `super`?

Comment: Yeah. But how is it changing with this placing before and after of `super` ?

Comment: So what order did you see when you logged before the super call, in the fragment itself, and after the super call? Were you able to draw any conclusions on the order that they are called in?

Comment: Here's a good article that explains the lifecycle callback sequence: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/the-android-lifecycle-cheat-sheet-part-iii-fragments-afc87d4f37fd